# Successfully installed rails-6.0.4 と出るものの、コマンドを実行すると cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError) になる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

初学者です。拙い質問ですが、どうかご助言頂けますでしょうか。

#### 現状/環境

VSCodeにてrails ver6.0.3をインストールを試みるが、
"Successfully installed rails-6.0.4" と出るものの
`rails -v` で確認する限り入っていない

Ruby 2.7.6
M1チップ
Big Sur ver 11.2.3

#### やりたいこと

ポートフォリオ作成の為、Railsをインストールしたい

#### 実際に出てるエラーメッセージ

`gem install rails -v 6.0.4` を入力すると
"Successfully installed rails-6.0.4"　と表示されるものの、
`rails -v` を入力すると以下のエラーが表示される。

エラー：

```
cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError)
```

#### 心当たり

過去にRubyバージョン を 3.0.1 にしましたが、ポートフォリオ作成の観点から2.7.6に戻しました。その時に変なことしてしまったのかもしれません。

#### 参考画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 心当たりがあるのなら、可能な限りRuby関連ソフトウェアが何も入っていない環境に戻してから、再度新規にインストールしてみるのが良いのでは？ 少しづつ版数が違うけれどこれらの記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[Ruby on Railsの環境構築 (macOS)](https://www.techpit.jp/courses/2/curriculums/3/sections/12/parts/40), [Mac M1 Big Sur にRuby / Railsをインストール 2021-01](https://qiita.com/kazutosato/items/6dea35e97f39d8d13e83), [macOS BigSur上にrbenvで Ruby on Rails開発環境を構築する](https://www.aise.ics.saitama-u.ac.jp/~gotoh/RoROnMacOSBigSur.html), [M1 MacにRubyとRailsの環境構築してみた](https://zenn.dev/osuzuki/articles/a535b2840bbea3)

Comment: kunif様　ご回答ありがとうございます。
再構築より始めます。

Answer (score 2):

まず、rails gem はインストールされています。`rails` コマンドが実行できるということは何かしらインストールされているということです。もしインストールされていないのであれば `rails` という実行可能ファイルが PATH から見つからないというエラーになります。rails gem がインストールされているものの実行すると `cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError)` エラーが出る、というのが今回の現象です。

ruby 2.7 においても ruby 3.0 においても etc gem は default gem（標準でインストールされている gem）です。これが見つからないということは、ruby の環境が何かしら壊れています。

ruby バージョンを変えたとのことですが、このときに rbenv や homebrew などのバージョン管理ツールを使わずにご自身で何かされたのであれば、そのとき何か壊してしまったのかもしれません。

原因究明して直していくこともできますが、今回の場合であれば一度すべてアンインストールしてしまって最初から環境構築するのが一番早そうです。

なお、ruby 2.7 は 2023 年 3 月に end of life が予定されています。何かしら使いたいライブラリで制限があるなどの事情が無い限り、今から新しく作るのであればより新しいバージョンの ruby を使うことをお勧めします。

Comment: nekketu様　前回に引き続き回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り一度全てアンインストールして、再度構築し直します

Comment: nekketu様
ここでいう”全て”というのは
ruby 3.1.2
rbenv
homebrew
gem
rails
ということになりますでしょうか。
ruby関連のプログラムのみ、MAC出荷時に戻すようなコマンドはありますでしょうか
初学者の為、勝手がわからず、全てアンインストールしても問題ないのか不安ですのでお伺いさせて戴きました

Comment: 私は Hiroki さんがどのようにインストールされたのかが分からないので、何がどこにインストールされているかが分かりません。rbenv で ruby をインストールされたのであれば rbenv ごとアンインストールすれば ruby も gem も消えます。homebrew で ruby をインストールされたのであれば homebrew からアンインストールすれば良いです。どのファイルが何に管理されていてどこに配置されているのかを考えながら削除してみてください。

Comment: nekketu様 ご回答ありがとうございます。
そうなりますと自分は、homebrewとrbenv両方でインストールしていたみたいです。他にもPATHをいじってしまっていたりします‍♂️
頂いたアドバイスをもとに一度やってみてそれでも進まないようであれば、新たに質問投稿いたします。
ご指導いただきありがとうございました